# PHPUnit: how to mock one specific method in class which is called from not mocked one

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, static-methods

Having class like following:

```
class MyClass{     

     public static function create($data){


         $dataModified= $self::doCurlRequest($data);

         //doing something else with data

         return $dataModifiedAlot;
     }

     public static function doCurlRequest($someData){
         //doing request here
     }

 }
```

is it possible to mock only the doCurlRequest($someData)? I tried this:

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{     

     public function testCreate(){

         $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('MyClass')->setMethods(array('doCurlRequest'))->getMock();

         $mock::staticExpects($this->any())
                ->method('doCurlRequest')
                ->with($someDataNeededForRequest)
                ->will($this->returnValue("some JSON rensponse"));

         $response = $mock::create($data);       

     }

 }
```

and the problem is that method doCurlRequest($someData) returns the real value instead of expected one :/ A I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the method in your class using `static::doCurlRequest()`.  `staticExpects` uses [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) to create the mock.  Because of this, the method needs to be called via `static` rather than `self` or `$this->` which will call the actual method.

Your class needs to look like this:

```
class MyClass{     

     public static function create($data){


         $dataModified= static::doCurlRequest($data);

         //doing something else with data

         return $dataModifiedAlot;
     }

     public static function doCurlRequest($someData){
         //doing request here
     }

 }
```

FYI: `staticExpects` was removed in PHPUnit 4.0

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/Release-Announcement-for-PHPUnit-4.0.0#backwards-compatibility-issues

Comment: Great, thanks. Btw I know about staticExpects, but I'm using PHPUnit 3.7 :)